# Use PiHole for Guest Network on OpenWRT router

Tags: openwrt, pihole

I followed [this tutorial](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/guestwifi/configuration_webinterface) to create a guest wifi, which is working great.

My PiHole is filtering out ads on my main wifi at `192.168.1.1`.

However, if I add `6,192.168.1.2` (which is my PiHole's static address) as the DHCP Option to the guest interface's advanced settings under the DHCP tab, none of my devices connected to the guest wifi are able to connect to the internet, e.g. ping google.com.

LAN is setup as `192.168.1.1`

GUEST is setup as `192.168.3.1`

My current firewall settings look like this:

> Guest => WAN: Input (Reject), Output (Allow), Forward (Reject)

I added Traffic Rules according to the tutorial mentioned above, for port 53 and port 67.

I probably need to add some firewall rule but I am not too savvy with OpenWRT's firewall. Possibly there is another solution too?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this issue:

Essentially, I added a traffic rule in the OpenWrt firewall to allow UDP packets from my Guest LAN to my main LAN 192.168.1.2 on port 53.

These are the steps I took, when adding a new `Traffic Rule`:

- Protocol: `UDP only`
- Source Zone: `Guest`
- Destination IP: `192.168.1.2`
- Destination Port: `53`
- All other values/options were left untouched

Now, all connected devices to the Guest network are being filtered through PiHole as well.